# In R, how can I transform to normalize residuals when I have a U-shaped Q-Q plot?

Tags: r, anova, data-transformation, residuals

I am running a two-way ANOVA with one random variable.  My histogram of the residuals is showing considerable (negative?) skew: 
[image]

And my Q-Q plot of the residuals shows a corresponding U-shaped curve:

[image]

Can someone suggest an appropriate transformation to normalize these residuals?  I have tried log and sqrt transform, but these aren't doing the trick - Q-Q plots look essentially identical.

Here's the residuals just in case anyone needs them:

```
resids<-c(0.0907115234404372, -0.00228847655956277, -0.0267884765595627, 
-0.0859262641306289, -0.0212262641306287, -0.0667262641306288, 
-0.0593952037730363, 0.0185047962269638, -0.0364802818046719, 
-0.0345802818046719, -0.0636802818046718, 0.0459197181953281, 
0.110319718195328, 0.00411971819532808, 0.0156218781924411, 0.0877218781924409, 
-0.0467325370980458, -0.0373134598697733, 0.0841865401302266, 
-0.0560134598697732, 0.150586540130227, -0.0111134598697733, 
0.152686540130227, -0.045845932936565, -0.0389459329365651, -0.0163459329365649, 
-0.00584593293656499, -0.015545932936565, 0.00425406706343501, 
0.0194540670634349, -0.0566459329365649, -0.0370459329365651, 
0.0271762555042805, -0.0518237444957197, -0.0459770706142297, 
-0.0256237444957197, 0.105910766841122, 0.0239136558615476, 0.0456136558615476, 
-0.0437396702569626, -0.00593967025696251, -0.0071396702569626, 
-0.0236257538123323, 0.0136019650946468, -0.0111257538123324, 
-0.00702575381233239, -0.0239257538123323, -0.0280284968467248, 
0.0705715031532752, -0.0504829121372117, -0.0429829121372116, 
-0.0193829121372118, -0.0509829121372116, 0.10563489248827, -0.0311651075117305, 
-0.0259651075117306, 0.0650348924882695, 0.0251893077787564, 
-0.00731069222124359, -0.0845911986230001, 0.0188349345620156, 
-0.00856506543798452, -0.0402650654379846, -0.00956506543798441, 
-0.0695650654379845, 0.0615349345620155, -0.0495650654379844, 
0.0476936955538023, -0.0414063044461976, 0.0333936955538023, 
-0.0451063044461977, -0.0531413637369638, -0.045694689855474, 
0.000385664780562678, 0.0940389908990729, -0.0195610091009271, 
-0.0254143352194374, -0.0284143352194373, 0.000298786199770751, 
-0.0942012138002293, -0.0013012138002293, 0.00800940250009097, 
-0.0193946496405897, 0.0119330692663895, 0.0370053503594103, 
-0.0113669307336104, -0.0499459456813103, -0.0415459456813103, 
-0.0229459456813104, -0.0300459456813102, 0.0462540543186898, 
0.0443540543186898, 0.0407540543186897, 0.0183540543186897, 0.0571540543186897, 
0.0363632617174681, -0.0610367382825319, 0.0981632617174681, 
0.0474632617174682, -0.0485367382825319, -0.0585367382825319, 
0.00866326171746823, 0.0131632617174682, 0.190063261717468, -0.0370367382825318, 
0.0362590810548065, 0.0105590810548064, -0.0385409189451935, 
0.0369590810548064, 0.0492590810548064, -0.0298409189451936, 
-0.0589915546215696, -0.00219155462156961, -0.0737915546215695, 
0.0181084453784304, -0.0104915546215696, 0.0627084453784306, 
-0.0674915546215695, -0.0622915546215694, -0.0274840518137136, 
-0.0470117707206927, 0.0133159481862863, 0.0356882292793073, 
-0.0581584446021826, -0.0386584446021827, 0.0445783565165312, 
-0.0369216434834687, -0.00882164348346892, 0.0411250303980211, 
-0.0485216434834688, -0.021339528891233, 0.0656387579342828, 
-0.0313612420657172, -0.023839528891233, -0.0142395288912331, 
-0.029639528891233, -0.0310499966187923, 0.0433500033812078, 
0.0617500033812077, -0.0366499966187923, -0.0621499966187924, 
0.0211500033812078, -0.0632499966187923, 0.0631500033812076, 
0.0819500033812077, -0.000349996618792314, -0.0129198942139448, 
-0.0450198942139448, 0.130180105786055, 0.138980105786055, -0.0668198942139449, 
-0.065919894213945, -0.0167652600956127, -0.00446526009561277, 
0.0310347399043871, 0.0220564530788714, 0.0179564530788714, 0.0407347399043871, 
0.0111347399043871, 0.0776564530788715, -0.00805388766299564, 
-0.0662538876629957, -0.0307083029534827, 0.0541461123370044, 
0.113446112337004, -0.0603320519387343, -0.0217320519387341, 
-0.0915320519387341, 0.113074320307902, -0.0297256796920982, 
0.0209743203079018, -0.0236256796920982, 0.0587743203079019, 
-0.0662256796920981, -0.0534256796920982, -0.0338256796920982, 
-0.083325679692098, 0.00277707299336427, -0.0294229270066357, 
0.0124770729933641, -0.0533229270066358, 0.146077072993364, 0.0317770729933642, 
-0.0685448001543059, -0.0316448001543057, -0.0575448001543057, 
0.146509615136181, 0.014109615136181, -0.0747903848638189, -0.0166777624015848, 
0.0308222375984151, 0.0914222375984151, 0.00242223759841509, 
-0.0389777624015848, -0.000977762401584981, 0.0269222375984151, 
-0.0204624068697834, 0.102637593130217, -0.0698624068697833, 
-0.0742624068697832, -0.0477624068697833, -0.00586240686978323, 
0.0955375931302167, 0.0890642743432923, 0.180464274343292, -0.044757438831192, 
-0.0723357256567077, -0.0680357256567077, -0.00925287584284296, 
-0.0209072911333299, -0.0347528758428428, 0.204647124157157, 
0.113207730323683, 0.00190773032368274, -0.0242922696763173, 
-0.0405922696763172, -0.0265922696763172, 0.0974077303236829, 
-0.0243922696763172, -0.0630922696763172, 0.0283077303236827, 
0.0582681073945803, -0.0279318926054197, -0.0236318926054198, 
-0.0272318926054196, -0.0347318926054196, -0.0801318926054198, 
-0.0626768408136609, 0.0253502995705317, -0.0571497004294683, 
0.200850299570532, -0.0440497004294684, -0.0357497004294682, 
0.0217502995705317, -0.0505861289667355, 0.0888138710332644, 
-0.0749861289667355, 0.0619138710332645, 0.0599138710332645, 
-0.0103861289667355, -0.0159861289667356, 0.00541387103326452, 
-0.0678160116680873, 0.0365839883319128, 0.0577839883319127, 
0.0136839883319126, 0.0878839883319127, 0.0160839883319128, 0.144683988331913, 
-0.0139160116680872, -0.0400766221886237, -0.0801766221886238, 
-0.0895766221886236, -0.00807662218862371, 0.0238233778113763, 
-0.0527766221886237, -0.0292766221886236, 0.00982337781137632, 
-0.00237662218862367, -0.0566766221886237, 0.0823492874218354, 
0.0203948721313485, -0.0382507125781646, -0.110305127868652, 
-0.0752051278686516, 0.153894872131348, 0.100494872131349, 0.0305948721313485, 
-0.0123051278686515, -0.0669051278686517, -0.0574913489020565, 
0.107108651097943, 0.0480086510979434, 0.0452086510979433, -0.101691348902057, 
0.00680865109794326, 0.0692086510979433, -0.0405913489020566, 
0.0349086510979433, 0.0499356114062059, -0.0297861017682783, 
-0.0142861017682785, 0.0234138982317216, 0.0147356114062058, 
0.0696356114062058, -0.0285643885937941, 0.0578818302164203, 
-0.0486181697835797, -0.0167181697835797, 0.0221818302164203, 
-0.0665338718584472, 0.00596612814155284, 0.0139661281415528, 
-0.0721338718584472, -0.0639338718584472, 0.119566128141553, 
-0.0489338718584471, -0.0740338718584472, 0.00296612814155295, 
-0.0787409112120181, -0.0295409112120182, -0.0417409112120182, 
0.0827531906259826, -0.0251468093740175, 0.0166531906259826, 
0.00825319062598262, -0.0569468093740175, -0.0354468093740175, 
0.0578531906259825, 0.0127531906259826, -0.0787468093740173)
```

Comment: Would you provide the original data so that it can be transformed, please? The residuals do not help with that.

Answer (score 7):

The `boxcox` function in the MASS package will give an appropriate range of $\lambda$ values for the Box-Cox transformation.  If you have not read the paper by Box and Cox, then you should.

Combine the suggested range with knowledge about the science that generated the data and some common sense to decide on a final value  (don't just use $\lambda=0.413$ because that gives the best answer, if the confidence interval includes $0.333$ and $0.5$ then look to see if a square root or cube root makes sense with the science and use the one that makes the most sense).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the reason why even you tried transformation, is that the Q-Q plot doesn't match a normal distribution. For example, as can be seen on the histogram, the gap between max and min is quite large. 
That is, the data set has a large big variance. How about trying another distribution? For example, the Weilbull distribution might be useful as it can flexibly fit data.

Comment: The variance is not relevant to the question, because it carries no information about the *shape* of the distribution of residuals.  The implication of using a normal QQ plot is that the regression assumes the residuals are approximately Normal.  What, then, would it mean to "try another distribution"?  Suppose you were to discover that the residuals indeed appear to be Weibull?  What would you do about the original regression?

Comment: The Q-Q plot shows how well the Theoretical Quantiles and Sample Quantiles are match. As you can see on that plot, the left side and right side of the plot seem so apart from the line, It is because of too lower or too large value of the data. So I meant, if I assume that data is arise from the Weibull distribution, That the Q-Q plot test show how well the Theoretical Quantiles (from now on It's Weilbull's quantile) and Sample Quantiles are match.

Comment: You mentioned that a normal QQ plot is that the regression assumes the residuals are approximately Normal, But, I think, as the Luke first, assume the normal distribution, then the QQ plot is used to test does really that data is from Normal distribution. However, the QQ plot is not always mean normal test, It's depends on the distribution what you assume. Also, I think to test whether it's Normal distribution using residual is Residual verses Fitted or Residuals verse Leverage Plot.